# RStudio Connection to Spark on IBM Watson Studio

Tags: r, apache-spark, rstudio, ibm-watson, sparklyr

I'm trying to connect to Spark from an RStudio instance on IBM Watson Studio but I'm getting the following error.

```
    No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8. Error in force(code) : 
    Failed during initialize_connection: attempt to use zero-length 
    variable name
    Log: /tmp/Rtmpdee7QC/file1b33141066_spark.log


    ---- Output Log ----
    hummingbird kernel
    http://localhost:8081/apsrstudio/agent/v1/kernel/hb-connect ; Time 
    Diff :1.31352798938751
    {"code": "import sparklyr._"} ; Time Diff :0.00552034378051758
```

Here's the code I'm using to create the connection:

```
    kernels <- load_spark_kernels()
    sc <- spark_connect(config = kernels[1])
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue! Seems like I was missing a Project Access Token. Project access tokens can be manually created as described [here](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/token.html?audience=wdp). Tokens can be created on the Settings page of your project. From the link shared above:

> Create an access token on the Settings page of your project. Only project admins can create access tokens. The access token can have viewer or editor access permissions. Only editors can inject the token into a notebook.

After adding a project access token, I could connect to Spark using the code provided in the question with no problems.

```
kernels <- load_spark_kernels()
sc <- spark_connect(config = kernels[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IBM Watson Studio on Cloud and using Rstudio in it, you should be using `list_spark_kernels()` to list the kernels.

```
kernels <- list_spark_kernels()
```

Then use spark_connect() to connect to it.
One more thing, do not upgrade the `sparklyr`, if you did, uninstall it.
Since sparklyr that Rstudio on watson studio cloud has is customized to allow to be able to connect to spark service from IBM Cloud.

```
sc <- spark_connect(config = kernels[1])
```

Uninstalling the sparklyr or removing your version of sparklyr will load the original sparklyr(customized).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried what you suggested and I'm still getting the exact same error.